# C#, Finding duplicates in arrays, Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#, arrays, duplicates

Can't figure out why the line `winningNumbers[i] += count;` comes up as outside the bounds of the array.

```
static int[] CheckWinningNumbers(int[][]lottoNumbers, int[]drawNumbers)
                {
                    int[] winningNumbers = new int[8];
                    for (int i = 0; i < lottoNumbers.Length; i++)
                    {
                        int k = 0;
                        int count = 0;
                        for (int j = 0; j < lottoNumbers[i].Length; j++)
                        {
                            if (lottoNumbers[i][j] == drawNumbers[k])
                            {
                                count +=1;
                            }
                            k += 1;
                        winningNumbers[i] += count;
                        }
                    }       
                return winningNumbers;
```

Comment: Are you sure that lottoNumbers never exeeds length 8?

Comment: winningNumbers should have length lottoNumbers.Length not 8 and k +=1 and winningNumbers[i] += count might go inside the if

Comment: mark initialization as `int[] winningNumbers = new int[lottoNumbers.Length];`

Comment: Edit to my prev. comment: winningNumbers[i] += count; might go outside the for(int j)

Answer (score 2):

Just replace

`int[] winningNumbers = new int[8];`

With

`int[] winningNumbers = new int[lottoNumbers.Length];`

As long as you are iterating `lottoNumbers.Length` the variable `i` will not exceed its boundaries.

### Edit

I ran it with the following data and it works

```
 int[][] lottoNumbers = { new[] { 1, 2 },                                       
                          new[]{ 3, 4 }, 
                          new[]{ 5, 6 }, 
                          new[]{ 7, 8 } };
 int[] drawNumbers = {1, 4, 5, 8};
```

I don't know what data you are testing it on but you are using [jagged arrays intead of multidimensional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597720/what-are-the-differences-between-a-multidimensional-array-and-an-array-of-arrays). this will **not** guarantee that all your sub arrays have the same length which might be problematic. If all the arrays have the same length and performance is not critical here I'd suggest you use [Multidimensional Arrays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx)